# 「いつまで待つつもり」 v.s. 「いつまで待っているつもり」

Tags: word-choice, aspect

Both seem to be possible. But what's their difference?

Instances of the former are everywhere, e.g. a line from 「[華麗なるギャツビー](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=ES7kAAAAQBAJ&pg=PT124&lpg=PT124&dq=%E2%80%9D%E3%81%84%E3%81%A4%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A7%E5%BE%85%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B%E3%81%A4%E3%82%82%E3%82%8A%E2%80%9D&source=bl&ots=3g9jYUYP27&sig=oVvLHXZN5ZW_MjUC3ln9UsNbmI8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj-mu2BxoPMAhXm5qYKHTTyD1UQ6AEIGzAA#v=onepage&q=%E2%80%9D%E3%81%84%E3%81%A4%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A7%E5%BE%85%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B%E3%81%A4%E3%82%82%E3%82%8A%E2%80%9D&f=false)」

> 「信じられるもんですか、あんな男」「いつまで待っているつもりです?」

The latter may be less common (?), but still some instances can be found, e.g. a line from 「[賭博黙示録カイジ](http://mangadget.net/comic_images/detail/997)」

[image]

[Sidenote]

In my mother tongue, Chinese, it will sound very weird to use aspect particles indicating progressiveness or continuity (such as 「在」 or 「着」) in such cases. That is, we will almost always opt for the equivalence of 「いつまで待つつもり」:

> √ 打算等到什么时候？
>
> × 打算等着到什么时候？
>
> × 打算在等到什么时候？

Therefore, it's hard for me to grasp the difference in nuance (if any) between the two usages in Japanese.

Comment: The problem with your last two Chinese sentences is that you mixed two incompatible types of constructions. 到 marks the boundary of the action while 着 and 在 present the verb as continuing state. You can make the sentence grammatical by writing it as something like 到什么时候之前等着. (ている in Japanese is often used to add a nuance of _continue doing something_, which is not necessarily translated in Chinese.)

Answer (score 4):

If you are asking this to someone who is already waiting for something *now*, whichever is fine. いつまで待つつもりですか may sound slightly blunter than いつまで待っているつもりですか, but the difference is very small.

If you are asking this to someone who is going to start waiting for something *in the future*, いつまで待つつもりですか will be the natural choice. いつまで待っているつもりですか may sound odd for the obvious reason.

> 「あした行くラーメン屋、大人気で、すごく並ばないと入れないんだって」「いつまで待つつもり？」「12時になっても入れなかったら諦めよう」

Answer (score 1):

「いつまで待つつもり」can be translated to "Until when do you plan to wait?"

「いつまで待っているつもり」can be translated to "Until when do you plan to be waiting?"

In other words, I think it's just a matter of tense (present vs. continuous)

As a side note, both of these phrases are often used sarcastically, with the underlying tone being "hurry the heck up" and/or "what the heck are you waiting for?"